# TimThumb - Can't change filename

Tags: php, timthumb

I'm using "TimThumb" function on my PHP website, 
but I got a problem about it that; I can't change filename.

```
<img src="thumb.php?src=blabla.jpg&w=300&h=200 />
```

And when I save an image, it is saved as "thumb.jpg"

How can I solve this problem? Could .htaccess solve it?

Comment: your question is unclear please explain in details? BTW TimThumb is a simple, flexible, PHP script that resizes images.

Comment: You do not need to change the optimized file name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the default 'save image as' name for an image generated in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507789/how-do-i-set-the-default-save-image-as-name-for-an-image-generated-in-php)